# How to check if a substring is repeated without using regex?

Tags: java, substring, repeat

I want to check if a String contains repeated substrings.

For example, how do I check `(bc)*` without using regex library in Java?

Comment: what counts a repeated substring, would even a double letter count, and do they have to be consecutive?

Comment: You could use a loop, although a finite state machine really is the best way to handle this situation. So that leads me to asking: why can't you use regex?

Comment: @Maljam A repeated substring would be (bc)+. As in, one or more instances of bc consecutively. For example: bc, bcbc, bcbcbc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply use this recursive algorithm:

```
public static boolean repeatedString(String str, String repeat, int lastIndex) {
    int next = str.indexOf(repeat, lastIndex+repeat.length());

    if(next == -1) return false;
    else if(next-lastIndex == repeat.length()) return true;
    else return repeatedString(str, repeat, next);
}
```

Call `repeatedString(str, "bc", -1)`, It's essentially checking if any two occurences of `repeat` are consecutive.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way would be to filter through each character and check to see if it starts with the substring that you are looking for.

```
public static int countSubstringOccurences(String st, String substring) {
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < st.length(); i++) {
        if(st.substring(i).startsWith(substring)) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

This will method will test each substring of the given String to see if it starts with the given substring, and increase the count by one each time it finds a match.